# Automating the entry of Pathfinder Stat Block

Tags: pathfinder-1e

How do I automate entering (not generate) statistics for a Pathfinder character or monster, and get some formatted text of a proper stat block that I can use in Microsoft Word or Adobe Indesign?

Comment: Have you looked at the Reddit threads on Pathfinder stat generators? They may be of use to you.

Comment: I am not looking to generate stats but being able to enter them and have a formatted stat block pop out suitable for pasting into Word or Indesign. Clarified my original questions

Comment: I think this question and your previous one might see better responses on Reddit or RPG forums/discussion boards.

Comment: @Ash if you have an answer to the question (or a good lead on a place to find the answer), please post it as an answer, not as a comment so that it can be voted on, critiqued, and preserved.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose If I was sure that it is an answer I would, I'm not certain that the output is what the OP wants since "some formatted text" is not really specific about what he's looking for as a finished product.

Comment: @Ash Please don’t answer in comments. See [this FAQ](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6533/321) for why your comment was removed.

Comment: @Ash I agree, the question is pretty unclear which is why I've voted to close until more details can be provided. Even so, posting potential answers is not allowed.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I know but again; the question is insufficiently specific for me to be confident that my suggestion actually constitutes an answer if I was confident in the lead I have I'd put it in the answers.

Comment: @Ash That’s already covered by the FAQ I linked you. Please give it a read. :)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I think I'm still missing something here, I think there's something in terms of how I worded the comment versus the intent of the comment that's causing me issues. I'll try to strike a better tone/balance in future.

Comment: It would help if we knew what constituted a 'proper stat block'... are you looking for something that looks like the Bestiary entries? Something more condensed? Something else? Is there a reason that [Mythweavers](https://www.myth-weavers.com/) *Generate Statblock* (p4 of a character sheet) doesn't work?